# How do I disassociate a Java file in my NetBeans project from the NetBeans IDE GUI builder?

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

I've built portions of my desktop application (Java) in the NetBeans IDE GUI builder, but wish to move away from the GUI builder as the it has grown cumbersome as the program itself has grown.

Is there a good way to disassociate a class, once created, from the GUI builder, and thus enable editing of the currently generated source code (which, as it is regenerated based on the GUI builder design, is protected from editing in NetBeans, and any edits would be overwritten)? I'm running NetBeans IDE v. 10.0.

Comment: Delete the `.form` file

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you! Never noticed those, as they didn't show up in the editor's file tree. Solved my problem perfectly!